# decorator function in django post_save

Tags: python, django, decorator

I have the following call

```
models.signals.post_save.connect(auto_pending_member_to_member, sender=MyUser)
```

Now I want my `auto_pending_member_to_membe`r function to have extra parameter redis_client. So I decided to write decorator

```
def pass_service_redis_client(f):
    def inner(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        return f(sender, instance, redis_client = service_redis_client, **kwargs)
    return inner
```

and

```
models.signals.post_save.connect(pass_service_redis_client(auto_pending_member_to_member), sender=MyUser)
```

here `service_redis_client` is a global variable, described in the same file with decorator function. But my `auto_pending_member_to_member` function described in other directory.

After `MyUSer` object is saving, my decorator function is not calling.

Comment: You don't need to use a custom function; you can use a [`functools.partial()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to pre-define a keyword argument: `partial(auto_pending_member_to_member, redis_client=service_redis_client)`.

Comment: `models.signals.post_save.connect(partial(auto_pending_member_to_member, redis_client=service_redis_client), sender=MyUser)` also didn't work. After save `auto_pending_member_to_member` not calling.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't say it was a solution, I don't know what is going on for you. Reduce the problem further, see if a simpler event hook is still called, etc. I merely wanted to point you away from creating a wrapper function here when there is a standard solution for adding default arguments.

Comment: if you remove your wrapper, do you see your signalhandler being called?