# Unable to run custom decorator after post_save signal

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-signals

I have a `post_save` signal which is run after any updates happens to a Profile, like so:

```
# removing the `dispatch_uid` parameter doesn't change anything
@receiver(post_save, sender=Profile, dispatch_uid="c_profile_invite")
def send_invitation_email(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # ... do things
```

I would like to run a custom decorator on the signal, after the post_save has been run, like so:

```
def my_test_decorator(func):
    print("outside the wrapper")

    def wrapper(request, board_id, board_name):
        print("INSIDE THE DECORATOR AFTER POST_SAVE")
        try:
            return func(request, board_id, board_name)
        except Exception:
            return Http404("Board not found")
    return wrapper

@my_test_decorator
@receiver(post_save, sender=Profile, dispatch_uid="c_profile_invite")
def send_invitation_email(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # ... do things
```

However, my method `my_test_decorator` doesn't run at all. However, if I switch places on the decorators then it **will** run but it will run **before** the `@receiver` decorator, not after.

What am I missing? Found [this 5 year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179682/decorator-function-in-django-post-save), but it was left unanswered so I'm trying again.

TYIA

Comment: did you try without `try/except` to see if you get some error message? Maybe you get some error but you don't know it.

Comment: @furas I have tried that, no dice. The method isn't even called from what I can see

Comment: maybe it needs the same arguments as original function. OR simply `receiver` assings original function to event `post_save` and adding `my_test_decorator` above `receiver` can't change it. You would have to change original `receiver`